# Populate Data of Multiple Folder in Drop down, on change of their Name, using ajax jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am new to AJAX. My requirement is to populate data in drop down. Suppose I have two drop down, In one drop down I have to populate different names of folders which are stored locally in our system. These folder contains different kind of files.

Now, what I have to do is that on change of these folder name we have to populate name of files of that particular folder in other drop down.

Comment: Show what you have tried ?

Comment: I using using above concept in reading xml value...that i am showing but unable to get desired result.....I am showing my code....but please offer us  help and code for reading files of local folder....actually most of this code written by someone else.....hope you are getting me...

Comment: Sorry dear...code is too long...it is not accepting..please offer your own help..

Comment: still no response...........is there anyone...who can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

This code gives you rough idea

```
<?php
// Dir drop down
echo "<select name='files' id='folder'>";
// set your dir
$dir = new DirectoryIterator("your dir");
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
           echo '<option value='.$fileinfo->getFilename().'>'.$fileinfo->getFilename().'</option>';
    }
}
echo "</select>";
?>
<br>
<select id="sub_dir">
<option>Select</option>
</select>

<script>
$('#folder').change(function() {
   $.getJSON('get_dir.php', {dir: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
       var box = $('#sub_dir');
       box.empty();
       if (data) {
           $.each(data, function(i, file) {
               box.append('<option avl="'+file+'">' + file + '</option>');
           });
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

get_dir.php

```
<?php
$dir = 'content_pages/' . $_GET['dir'];
if (!preg_match('/\.\./', $_GET['dir'])) { // don't allow to traverse directories
    // Check to see if $dir is a valid directory
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        echo json_encode(array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.')));
    } else {
        echo "null";
    }
}
?>
```

**Reference**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#114184

https://www.sitepoint.com/list-files-and-directories-with-php/

Comment: thanks a lot to @ranjeet...hoping from others ...that provide idea in java  as well........please help us out.

Comment: Wow.........great.....is there any Java developer, who could assist to solve this problem........or it can not get done....please add your comment...i am newborn to this technology...

Comment: i don't work in java technology. I am busy with my projects. But i tried at weekend to find solution in java.

Comment: you can try https://www.google.co.in/search?q=get+directory+and+sub+directory+listing+in+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=8QdEV6sMyYKgA4PGrKgO#